# how to update the flag bits in TCL file after every run?

Tags: automation, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am writing automation script, where test runs if the particular flag bit is set to one in data.tcl file. 
After completing the first task, I need to reset the MAC flag value to 0 and I need to set xmac flag file 1 and remaining flags to 0.

before running test script flag values in data.tcl

```
set mac 1 
set xmac 0 
set fea 0 
set fea1 0
```

after 1st run: expected content of data.tcl file:

```
  set mac 0 
  set xmac 1 
  set fea 0 
  set fea1 0
```

after 2nd run: expected content of data.tcl file:

```
  set mac 0 
  set xmac 0 
  set fea 1 
  set fea1 0
```

after 3rd run: expected content of data.tcl file:

```
  set mac 0 
  set xmac 0 
  set fea 0 
  set fea1 1 


   fileutil::replaceInFile data.tcl 30 1 0
```

The above command reset the value at location 31 to 0 but in my case each flag as different length names so we can't use the location pointer to set and reset the flags 
  I tried some commands using fileutil package but i could not get some correct results. Could you please help me with this code to set and reset flags after every run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to come up with a way to do the mapping that doesn't need indices into the file.

```
proc setDataState {filename mapping} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
    close $f

    set f [open $filename "w"]
    foreach line $lines {
        if {[regexp {^(\s*set\s+(\w+)\s+)\w+(.*)$} -> head key tail] && [dict exists $mapping $key]} {
            set line $head[dict get $mapping $key]$tail
        }
        puts $f $line
    }
    close $f
}
```

So that will let you change the file in a controlled way, perhaps like this:

```
setDataState data.tcl {
    mac 0 
    xmac 1 
    fea 0 
    fea1 0 
}
```

OK, so that does the edits, but the real key is that you can provide the state dictionary via a variable; that lets you do much more sophisticated stuff:

```
# This shuffles the “1” along
set statedict [dict create  mac 0  xmac $mac  fea $xmac  fea1 $fea]
setDataState data.tcl $statedict
```

---

I think you'd actually be better off using an SQLite database to control your code (and collate the results too). But that's a much bigger change.

Comment: I tried the code, its adding empty line to data.tcl but its not changing the flag bit value. Could you check  it once ..